# Share state between tests that run in parallel with XUnit.net

Tags: xunit.net

I have a set of xunit.net tests that need to share state. Hopefully, I would like these tests to run in parallel. So I would want the runner to do:

- Create the shared fixture
- Run **in parallel** all the tests using that fixture

When reading the the xunit doc, it says that to share state between test classes, I need to define a 'collection fixture' and then but all my test classes into that new collection (ex: `[Collection("Database collection")]`). But when, I put my test class in the same fixture, they don't run in parallel anymore so it beats the purpose :(

Is there a built-in way to do what I want in XUnit?

My fallback will be to put my shared state into a static class.

Comment: Could you share an example of what you want to test?

Comment: For example, I need to create a user in the database and that user will be shared in read-only mode by a set of tests that will run in parallel.

Comment: It's a shame there's no clear example how to do this. I've tried a whole bunch of combinations but none of them work. If I get it working I'll post an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend xUnit using the [AssemblyFixture example](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/main/AssemblyFixtureExample/Samples.cs) from the samples pasted below  to create a fixture which can the accesses by tests while running in parallel.

Using this method the fixture is created before the tests and then injected into the tests which reference it. I use this to create a user which is then shared for that specific set run.

There is also a nuget package [**`xunit.assemblyfixture`**](https://github.com/kzu/xunit.assemblyfixture):

```cs
using System;
using Xunit;

// The custom test framework enables the support
[assembly: TestFramework("AssemblyFixtureExample.XunitExtensions.XunitTestFrameworkWithAssemblyFixture", "AssemblyFixtureExample")]

// Add one of these for every fixture classes for the assembly.
// Just like other fixtures, you can implement IDisposable and it'll
// get cleaned up at the end of the test run.
[assembly: AssemblyFixture(typeof(MyAssemblyFixture))]

public class Sample1
{
    MyAssemblyFixture fixture;

    // Fixtures are injectable into the test classes, just like with class and collection fixtures
    public Sample1(MyAssemblyFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void EnsureSingleton()
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, MyAssemblyFixture.InstantiationCount);
    }
}

public class Sample2
{
    MyAssemblyFixture fixture;

    public Sample2(MyAssemblyFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void EnsureSingleton()
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, MyAssemblyFixture.InstantiationCount);
    }
}

public class MyAssemblyFixture : IDisposable
{
    public static int InstantiationCount;

    public MyAssemblyFixture()
    {
        InstantiationCount++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Uncomment this and it will surface as an assembly cleanup failure
        //throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't want to share state between tests, you just want to share the setup required for the test to run.  You can read all about how to do that in xUnit here (there are pretty examples): http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html

If you happen to use Entity Framework I wrote something about it here too: https://robertengdahl.blogspot.com/2017/01/testing-against-entityframework-using.html

Comment: You are right. I used the wrong words. I want to share *setup* and not *state*. That being said, if we look at your first link, what I want to do is a CollectionFixture. To reuse the **same** collection fixture (instantiate it only once) for multiple test classes, all test classes must be placed in the same [Collection]. Then, if they are in the same [Collection], they won't run in parallel anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you wanted to run these in parallel.  Since the running in parallel does not require the same fixture instance, you can just have the fixture instance being a member variable for the test class, as recommended and shown in the second link.  You'll get the speed of parallel test, and the safety of isolated tests.

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl Nether of your links work anymore.  Can you update?  Looks like the first one should be https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.  However, if that is the case, then I don't see how that page about shared content answers this question.  The data shared by Class fixtures only gets shared between tests in the same class, and the Collection Fixtures suffer from the very problem outlined in the question.